# Can't load 'firewatir' gem in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, watir, firewatir

I want to run cucumber command in rails 3 controllers,but I add 'gem firewatir' to gemfile,
when I 'rails server', I got this error,and page shows "Internal Server Error".

```
[2011-03-24 14:32:05] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-03-24 14:32:05] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12) [universal-darwin10.0]
[2011-03-24 14:32:05] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=91734 port=3000
[2011-03-24 14:32:06] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `cache' for :active_support:Symbol
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:74:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:213:in `start'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:30
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
    script/rails:6:in `require'
    script/rails:6
```

If I don't add 'gem firewatir' to gemfile, rails server can run,but when run the cucumber command, I get this error:

```
no such file to load -- firewatir (LoadError)
```

Anyone ever met this issue,or who know how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: What version of the firewatir gem are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a known (and fixed) problem: [Watir and Rails 3.0.X incompatible](http://jira.openqa.org/browse/WTR-474)

Comment: Problem is fixed in trunk, but this has not been released yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the same thing since the stacktrace doesn't include any lines from commonwatir/firewatir. It could be something different, but can't say for sure.